# Lampp does not show the cause of error

Tags: lampp

I am working on php files, but when there is an error, it does not tell me the cause or the number of line containing the error, only there is a message on the page" the localhost page isn't working"

Comment: check the apache logs

Comment: How?, I am a beginner..

Comment: It deppends on your distro... ususually apache log is at /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At  the top of your PHP file, put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

When you are in dev mode.  When you are done w/ development, take it back out or comment it.